# upgrade MongoHQ prevents sails-mongo to connect in prod env

Tags: mongodb, heroku, express, sails.js

I am using **SailsJS 0.10.5.**

I purchased a production MongoDB from Heroku and it created a variable with the new database url as follows:

```
mongodb://heroku:**password**@candidate.32.mongolayer.com:10485,candidate.13.mongolayer.com:10455/app123
```

However, when running the app in production environment only, the app fails to connect to database:

```
 A hook (`session`) failed to load!
 Could not load Connect session adapter :: connect-mongo
     at new MongoStore (/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:115:19)
     at validateDatabaseName (/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib
/mongodb/db.js:235:59)
     at Hook.Session.initialize (/app/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/session/index.js:20
5:37)

 Error from adapter:
 Error: database names cannot contain the character '.'
     at new Db (/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js
```

Note that when I copied the string locally and ran the app it worked perfectly.

I saw some workarounds suggest using Mongoose, but I want to stick to connect-mongo / sails-mongo

**EDITED**

I now managed to connect to the db by removing the replica set and simply add:

```
mongodb://heroku:**password**@candidate.32.mongolayer.com:10485/app123
```

However, a new error arrived:

```
 Error: Error setting TTL index on collection : sessions
     throw message;
 at /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:700

 at commandHandler (/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo

 at Cursor.close (/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb

 at /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1882:9
 at Server.Base._callHandler (/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb

 at /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/se
```

It keeps crashing the app.
Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup and download [mongo-uri](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-uri) to parse the url automatically